# Targeting specific table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following code which works fine except that it is appending the rows to every table on my page.

How would I target a specific table in the code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('/api/getUsers',
    function(json) {
      var tr;
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].UserName + "</td>");

        // Format the phone number
        formatted_phone = json[i].PhoneNumber.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');

        tr.append("<td>" + formatted_phone + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Email + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td><button type=button class=\"btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block roster-button active\" data-toggle=modal data-target=#removeRoster>Remove</button></td>");
        tr.append("<td></td>");
        tr.append("<td><button type=button class=\"btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block roster-button active\" data-toggle=modal data-target=#updateTime>View/Update Time</button></td>");

        $('table').append(tr);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Give your table an id and then use `$('table#tableId').append(tr);` See: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: use an id or class as identifier instead of only `$('table')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add an identifier to your table, and update the selector accordingly.

```
<table id="the-table">
```

Then change this line:

```
$('#the-table').append(tr);
```

If you wanted to apply this to multiple tables but not all, use a common class in lieu of the id.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to select an element. You can use the `eq`, `id`, `class` just to name a few.

```
<table class="tbl" id="tbl">

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('table#tbl').append(tr);//using ID
$('table.tbl').append(tr);//using class
$('table:eq(0)').append(tr);//using zero based index
</script>
```

Check out the selectors on the jQuery site:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Also worth noting that using `$('table').eq(0)` will give you better performance in newer browsers than `$('table:eq(0)')`.